# touchend event not fired on iOS when it starts on a div

Tags: javascript, ios, dom-events, touch-event

I have some problem with a touchend event on iOS:

```
var target;

window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    target = $('mydiv');
    target.addEvents({ 'touchstart': onTouchStart });
});

function onTouchStart(){

    console.log('touch start');
    target.addEvents({ 'touchend': onTouchEnd });
}

function onTouchEnd(){

    console.log('touch end');
}
```

Everything should work fine, but touchend is not fired when I'm on this div.
This div is nothing special, it's just a wrapper for some images and has this CSS:

```
#albums-wrapper{ position: absolute; width: 10000px; height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
target.addEvents({ 'touchend': onTouchEnd });
```

target is undefined, I believe

Comment: You're right Jarret, when I was writing the example I forgot to make the target global. I just edit my post, sorry.

Comment: Why is it not target = $('#albums-wrapper'); ?